# RabbitMQ with nodejs

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

Am trying to establish connection with RabbitMQ from nodejs program. But its not establishing a connection, neither throwing an error. My code is as below. Any suggestions please.

```
var amqp = require('amqp');
var connection = amqp.createConnection({url:"amqp://guest:guest@localhost:15672"});

connection.on('ready', function(){

    var q = connection.queue('jsonmsg', function(q) {
        console.log('connected');
        q.bind("#");
        q.subscribe(function (message) { 
            console.log('on connection' + message);
        });
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 16):

Looks like you are connecting to the management port `15672`.
The standard AMQP port is `5672`.  However, using the `amqp://` protocol should automatically set this port.

So, try to change:

```
var connection = amqp.createConnection({url:"amqp://guest:guest@localhost"});
```

RabbitMQ docs for url are [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html).

Comment: Hey it works fine now. Thank you so much :) Am able to connect to RabbitMQ now.